# Почему в переменную initial я могу передавать несколько значений?

Tags: функции, python-3.6

Код взят из книги "Bite of Python "

```
def total(initial=5, *numbers,**keywords):
    count = initial 
    for number in numbers:
        count += number
    for key in keywords:
        count += keywords[key]
    return count

print(total(100,100, vegetables=50, fruits=100))
```

Comment: В книге "Bite of Python" действительно это сказано?

Answer (score 0):

Не можете. В переменную initial в коде передается только одно значение - 100. Второе значение 100 передается в `numbers`.